# nullpointerexception with inserting a gallery in tabview

Tags: java, android, gallery, nullpointerexception, tabview

Hi i have currently created a tab view in my app.. The tabs worked fine until i begin to create a gallery within one of them. Could someone please have a look for me.. In the logcat the nullpointer exception seems to be on line - photos.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter());

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Does the gallery work when you add it to a non-tabbed activity?

Comment: @Phonon i havent tried that.. im following a tutorial religiously and the tabs worked when i tested it then.. but as soon as i inserted the gallery it wont work... the tutorial is based on adding the gallery to a tab.. im so confused

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference gallery you either have to call setContentView(R.layout.listedsites)  or inflate it...as of now nothing is in your Activity view hierarchy so  `((Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery));` returns null.

Also, it seems to me you only want the gallery in your "gallery" tab so do your gallery logic in the corresponding activity.